# How to separate groups of radio choices in one page? They are in conflict

Tags: python, django

I am making a kind of a survey(evaluation).

My web has multiple radio choices(fields) in one page.

For example, I have 3 questions in a page, each has 5 radio choices. If I select the choice 3 in No.1 question and then the 4 in No.2 question, No.1 choice disappeared(choice 3). I guess it's conflict between No.1 and No.2.

So, I can pick just one choice for all questions.
[image: first selection]

### ----------------------------------------------------------

[image: second selection(first one disappeared)]

I guess something wrong since I display many forms (not one form) in same page. But I don't know why.
Help me...

My Code is following (Never mind about Korean)

**html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post" id='evaluate_answer_form' novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% for q, form in questions %} # q:question object / form:answer form
      <p>
        {# Include the hidden fields #}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        {# Include the visible fields #}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
              {{ field.errors }}
              {{ q.ask }} {{ field }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>

    {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
AGREEMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('5', '매우 동의함'),
    ('4', '동의함'),
    ('3', '보통임'),
    ('2', '동의하지 않음'),
    ('1', '매우 동의하지 않음')
)
   class Meta:
       model = Answer
       fields = ['text']

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # input = question & course
       question = kwargs.pop('question')
       course = kwargs.pop('course')

       self.question = question
       super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if question.ans_type == 'a':
           self.fields['text'] = forms.ChoiceField(
               choices = AGREEMENT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect()
           )

       elif question.ans_type == 's':
           self.fields['text'] = forms.CharField()
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
       ask = models.CharField('질문 내용', max_length=300)
       ans_type = models.CharField('대답 유형', max_length=10, default='s')
       response = models.ForeignKey(Response, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField('대답', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    choice = models.IntegerField('점수', blank=True, null=True)
    answered = models.BooleanField('대답 여부', default = False)

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
(...)
c = course # Course object
questions=[]
for q_set in c.questionset_set.all(): #Course <- Questionset <- Question
    for q in q_set.question_set.all():
        answer = Answer()
        answer.question = q
        answer.response = response
        answer.save()
        questions.append([q, AnswerForm(instance=answer, question=q, course=c)])
        questions.sort(key=lambda x:x[0].id) #sort

return render(request, 'tas/evaluate_answer.html', {'questions': questions})
```

Comment: I don't really understand the code you have posted - where is the rest of that view, and why did you post that bit of it - but you should probably use the `prefix` kwarg when instantiating your forms.

Comment: My question was not enough to understand. My bad.

Comment: The problem was because of HTML radio input's name. All questions have same name, so html get just one value from all question. I corrected it.